# How to set value in formik?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I am working with a functional component in react native, and I want to store the image URI in the initial state of Formik.

I am getting the Image URI in the _pickimage function but I am stuck in how to pass that to Formik's initial state.

How I can set the URI value to the initial state.

and

if there a way to store other custom values from functional state to Formik initial state?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Picker, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global'
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

export default function form(props) {
    const { register } = props
    const getPermissionAsync = async () => {
        if (Constants.platform.ios) {
            const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
            }
        }
    }
    const _pickImage = async () => {
        getPermissionAsync();
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1
        });
        if (!result.cancelled) {
            console.log(result.uri)
         // Getting Image URI value here
        }
    }
    return (      
            <View >
                <Formik
                    initialValues={
                        {
                            image: '',                      
                        }}

                    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {                      
                            register(values);          
                            console.log(values);
                            actions.resetForm(); 
                    }}                    
                >
                    {
                        (formikprops) => (
                            <View>
                                <Button
                                    title="image"
                                    icon="add-a-photo" mode="contained"
                                    onPress={() => { _pickImage(formikprops.handleChange('image')) }}
                                />
                                {formikprops.values.image && formikprops.values.image.length > 0 ?
                                    <Image source={{ uri: formikprops.values.image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} /> : null}

                                <Button title="submit" color="coral" onPress={formikprops.handleSubmit} />
                            </View>
                        )
                    }
                </Formik>

            </View>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of `setFieldValue` function from formik like

```
const _pickImage = async (setFieldValue, field) => {
        getPermissionAsync();
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1
        });
        if (!result.cancelled) {
            console.log(result.uri)
         // Getting Image URI value here
           setFieldValue(field, result.uri)
        }
    }

    ----

    <Button
        title="image"
        icon="add-a-photo" mode="contained"
        onPress={() => { _pickImage(formikprops.setFieldValue, 'image') }}
    />
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using MUI v5 and `useFormik` hook. I had to access the `setFieldValue` form `formik` object to make it work.

Below is excerpt from my code.

```
const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    car: '',
  },
  validationSchema: carSchema,
  onSubmit: (values) => {},
});

... 

<Autocomplete
   id="autocomplete"
   options={cars}
   getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.code} - ${option.label}`}
   renderOption={(props, option) => (
     <Box component="li" {...props}>
       {option.code} - {option.label}
     </Box>
   )}
   onChange={(e, value) => {
     formik.setFieldValue(
     'car',
     `${value.code} - ${value.name}`,
     );
   }}
   renderInput={(params) => (
   <TextField
     {...params}
     id="textField"
     name="cars"
     label="Cars"
     onChange={formik.handleChange}
     onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
     inputProps={{
       ...params.inputProps,
       autoComplete: 'new-password',
     }}
     error={formik.touched['car'] && Boolean(formik.errors['car'])}
     helperText={formik.touched['car'] && formik.errors['car']}
   />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

### If you want change value from initial state outside of form

Simple answer:

```json
package.json: {
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
}
```

Change Formik initial value:

```js
userForm.initialValues["key"] = "Your new value";
```

With more details:

```js
export namespace UserModificationsNS {
  /** User Form Fields for render through in `.map` */
  export const userFormFields: Readonly<UserModificationsProps.UserField>[] = [
    { name: "f_name", type: "text" },
    { name: "l_name", type: "text" },
    { name: "username", type: "text" },
    { name: "password", type: "text" },
    { name: "email", type: "text" },
    { name: "phone", type: "text" },
    { name: "national_code", type: "text" },
    { name: "personal_code", type: "text" },
  ];
}
```

```js
export interface UserModificationForm extends Accounting {
  /*Another Fileds*/
}
```

```js
const userData: {
  success: boolean;
  data: UserModificationsProps.UserModificationForm;
} = await api.requestHandler(`${uri}/id=${userId}`, method);

if (userData.success) {
  UserModificationsNS.userFormFields.map(
    (userField: UserModificationsProps.UserField) => {
      // Here you can find your solution
      userForm.initialValues[userField.name] =
        userData.data[userField.name];
    }
  );
dispatch(UserModificationsState.setRole(userData.data.role));
}
```

### If you want change value inside of form

```js
{
  React.Children.toArray(
    UserModificationsNS.userFormFields.map(
      (field: UserModificationsProps.UserField) => (
        <FormControl sx={{ width: formControlResponsiveWidth }}>
          <TextFieldController
            label={t(`userModifications.userForm.${field.name}`)!}
            fieldType={field.type}
            inputName={field.name}
            value={userForm.values[field.name]}
            onChange={userForm.handleChange}
            error={
              userForm.touched[field.name] &&
              Boolean(userForm.errors[field.name])
            }
            helper={userForm.errors[field.name]}
          />
        </FormControl>
      )
    )
  );
}
```